# How to fix could not find function error while building lm model in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, olsrr

To explain the issue, I created the simple app you see below. I have no problem using the mtcars dataset directly, but when the issue is reactive (or master in the example), I get the *could not find function "master"* error. No matter what I tried, I couldn't overcome this issue, so I'm asking for your assistance.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    verbatimTextOutput("txt1"),
    verbatimTextOutput("txt2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  master <- reactive({
    mtcars
  })
  
  model1 <- reactive({
    olsrr::ols_step_both_p(lm(hp~.,data = mtcars))
  })
  
  model2 <- reactive({
    olsrr::ols_step_both_p(lm(hp~.,data = master()))
  })
  
  output$txt1 <- renderPrint({
    summary(model1()$model)
  })
  
  output$txt2 <- renderPrint({
    summary(model2()$model)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about shiny, but it seems that you didn't define `master` as a function. So when you call `master()` inside `model2`, it doesn't know what you mean.

You could either define it as a funcion, possiblysomething like:

```
master <- reactive({
  function(){mtcars}
})
```

Or calling `master` as an object:

```
model2 <- reactive({
  olsrr::ols_step_both_p(lm(hp~.,data = master))
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but sadly none of them work.